# Could not load the "sharp" module using the win32-x64 runtime (Strapi)

Tags: node.js, strapi, nvm, sharp

I used to use a Node.js v16.x installed locally to run Strapi which worked well.

But recently I had to update it to Node.js v18.x due to another project, so I installed NVM to manage multiple Node.js versions on my PC - and now I want to use Strapi with the new Node.js but I can't even start the develop mode anymore. There's a problem with the packge Sharp.

I'm not sure weather the issue with the package Sharp started because of the new Node version or NVM. As the Node installed (v18.17.0) is listed as compatible on Shap package npm page ([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp?activeTab=readme)), I guess the problem is with NVM.

```
nvm list

  * 18.17.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    16.14.2
```

My dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.16.2",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.16.2",
    "@strapi/provider-email-amazon-ses": "4.16.2",
    "@strapi/provider-upload-aws-s3": "4.16.2",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.16.2",
    "@strapi/utils": "4.16.2",
    "pg": "8.11.3",
    "reach": "1.0.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "sharp": "^0.33.1",
    "slugify": "1.6.6",
    "strapi-plugin-config-sync": "1.2.3",
    "strapi-plugin-email-designer": "2.2.1",
    "strapi-plugin-entity-relationship-chart": "4.14.6",
    "strapi-plugin-import-export-entries": "1.23.1",
    "strapi-plugin-notes": "1.1.2",
    "strapi-plugin-placeholder": "4.4.0",
    "strapi-plugin-publisher": "1.5.6",
    "styled-components": "5.2.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.x.x <=18.x.x",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  }
```

I've already tried to run the commands suggested on log (attached below) but nothing worked.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Hi, you need BuildTools and Python. https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp Scroll to Windows prerequisites

Comment: If you are on ARM, then you need BuildTools for ARM, witch available  only with Visual Studio

Comment: Hi @antokhio, thanks for your help. It was a pain in the a** trying to make it work with that solution - I had to install a lot of heavy libraries/packages (10~15GB), plus additional configurations etc. I even tried to run the project with Docker but the issue persists so I think it's something with the latest version of sharp. I added a answer below.

Comment: Just a guess but you may have `sharp` installed globally, you can try `npm list -g`, I had once issues because of globally installed package…

Comment: Hi, I faced this issue on Linux just recently. This issue might help. https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/3911

Answer (score 5):

I was not able to fix it, not sure if it's something wrong with the sharp latest version 0.33.1 (that I had updated on my project).

I even tried to run the Strapi with Docker on a Linux image (`node:18-alpine`) but that issue still happen:

```
Error: Could not load js config file
/opt/node_modules/strapi-plugin-placeholder/strapi-server.js: Could not load the "sharp" module using the linuxmusl-x64 runtime.

Possible solutions:
- Ensure optional dependencies can be installed:
  npm install --include=optional sharp
  yarn add sharp --ignore-engines
- Ensure your package manager supports multi-platform installation:
  See https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#cross-platform
- Add platform-specific dependencies:
  npm install --os=linuxmusl --cpu=x64 sharp
  npm install --force @img/sharp-linuxmusl-x64
- Consult the installation documentation:
  See https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install

at loadJsFile (/opt/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/core/app-configuration/load-config-file.js:18:13)
at Module.loadFile (/opt/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/core/app-configuration/load-config-file.js:37:14)
at Object.loadPlugins (/opt/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/core/loaders/plugins/index.js:90:41)
at async Strapi.loadPlugins (/opt/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/Strapi.js:310:5)
at async Promise.all (index 3)
at async Strapi.register (/opt/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/Strapi.js:340:5)
at async Strapi.load (/opt/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/Strapi.js:424:5)
at async Object.develop (/opt/node_modules/@strapi/admin/dist/_chunks/index-ffd2f664.js:1245:28)
at async develop (/opt/node_modules/@strapi/admin/dist/_chunks/develop-da585b1e.js:52:5)
at async Command.parseAsync (/opt/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:923:5)
at async Module.runStrapiCommand (/opt/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/commands/index.js:124:3)
```

The only solution was to downgrade to the previous version I was using (0.32.6), then it's working again.

Comment: I ended up here having the same issue (also with strapi) and using sharp 0.33.2. By downgrading to 0.32.6 strapi is starting again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Update your package manager

`npm install -g npm@latest`

2. Clear the cache

`npm cache clean -f`

3. Then Terminate batch job and run again

`npm run dev`

or

`npm run start`

Comment: This seemed to work for me, had an issue with Qwik.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure optional dependencies are installed:

```bash
npm install --include=optional sharp
```

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is related to the sharp error: `Could not load the "sharp" module using the win32-x64 runtime` and not specifically with Strapi.

It looks like sharp needs some builds to run in Windows and in `/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js` (line 13) you can notice that they listed a couple of paths:

```js
const paths = [
  `../src/build/Release/sharp-${runtimePlatform}.node`,
  '../src/build/Release/sharp-wasm32.node',
  `@img/sharp-${runtimePlatform}/sharp.node`,
  '@img/sharp-wasm32/sharp.node'
];
// as of February 17, 2024
```

To fix this error in Windows (using PowerShell terminal and not WSL) I installed [@img/sharp-win32-x64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@img/sharp-win32-x64) with `npm i @img/sharp-win32-x64 --save-optional` (notice the --save-optional flag) so when I run the same project in a Linux environment, npm will ignore @img/sharp-win32-x64 and safely continue.

This way in my particular case I am able to run my NodeJS project + sharp in Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your npm package is not updated. When your package isn't matching with the sharp package.
Easily Solving way is update your npm.

`npm install -g npm@latest`

if not working Clear the cache

`npm cache clean -f`

Then install the dependencies

`npm i sharp`

Hope working.